# Did Spyro elope with Cynder?

Tags: spyro

At the end of *The Legend of Spyro: Dawn of the Dragon* (2008), Spyro and Cynder ran away.

So did they elope? Because most people who run away together either elope or marry in secret.

Comment: They lived happily ever after; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5TaemHNl0kU&feature=youtu.be&t=1h1s

Comment: I guess Flash questions got boring.

Answer (score -2):

Yeah, I think so cause Cynder said "I love you" to Spyro and If you listen closely you can hear him say it back. 
but it's still open to interpretation.
Plus it is conformed by Wikipedia that Spyro and Cynder were truly in love, so they would not have split up, but the game never said what happened to them after they ran away, it only confirmed that they were a couple.

Comment: If your answer is just "probably yes", perhaps you could add an explanation of why you think so.

Comment: Wikipedia is not a solid source of info given that it's basically fan-written.